# How to use a microphone array with the standard pi-3 audio connector

Tags: pi-3, audio

I've got this [double array microphone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microphone_array), that i got with my [audio-card](http://se.creative.com/p/sound-blaster/sound-blaster-z) *(for my gaming rig)*, and i want to use it with my pi-3 to create some kind of voice tracker.
[image: Voice Tracker]

Does the audiojack on the pi-3 support array mic setups? If so, is there a library for it, or how would i go about separating the 2 microphones?

*(To clarify, the microphone array has 2 mics connected through one standard audiojack connector. Aka I need to be able to separate the 2 microphones from one another in order to be able to use them for triangulating sound sources.)*

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/p/manyears/wiki/Main_Page/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 3.5 mm audio jack in the Pi is sound *output*, and not for input. If you need audio input, you need to acquire some kind of sound card. There are a lot to choose from, using GPIO, I<sup>2</sup>S or USB to communicate with the Pi.

As for directional recording, as far as I can tell, the beam forming microphone is basically two omni-directional microphones next to each other. That is not dissimilar to a stereo microphone, and I expect you will find that one is in the left, and the other is in the right channel. http://support.creative.com/kb/ShowArticle.aspx?sid=107797

Comment: Kolla på Kjell&Co efter ljudkort.